# How to rename multiple files while keeping extension based on provided txt file?

Tags: linux, rename

I have a folder with many files that look like:

```
A1_R1.fastq   
A2_R1.fastq
A3_R1.fastq
```

I would like to rename the files based on a text file keeping the _R1.fastq but changing the A# to a specific samples name (example):

```
A1_R1.fastq  KUG_R1.fastq 
A2_R1.fastq  AUG_R1.fastq
A3_R1.fastq  TRY_R1.fastq
```

I'd also like an output directory which contains all my newly names .fastq files.

I tried this to no avail (only a few were renamed):

```
ls *.fastq| paste -d' ' - $PATH/txt | xargs -n2 mv
```

Thank you.

Comment: No need to list any files. Just run the contents of the text file `txt`. Inexistent files will just throw a file not found (harmless). Or toss the errors to `/dev/null`. `xargs -n2 bash -c 'echo mv $1 outputdir/$2' {} < txt`. Remove the echo to actually rename the files.

Comment: Or you can use a simple `while loop` and in the loop `mv` the files. `while read src dst; do mv $src outputdir/$dst; done < txt`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly!